# Database Link vs. NFS

Tags: database, oracle, nfs, database-link

What would be faster to migrate data from an old Oracle DB server to a new server, using a database link, or create a shared directory via NFS between old and new server to move data?

Comment: The two options suggest two different strategies for migrating the data. So who can tell?

Comment: I would opt for the database link and Oracle Datapump if you have that option.

Comment: Initially, my vote goes to Data Pump. On a second thought, *it depends*. What exactly do you plan to move? The whole database? Only one user? Which database version do you use? If it is 12c, you could go with a pluggable database (*unplug* it here, *plug* there). I'd say that copying data via a database link is the slowest option you might choose, so - unless there's just a very small amount of data and a few tables, I'd avoid that.

Comment: its 11g R2, i am moving the whole databse, its about 300 GB size, i am migrating from existing physical server to new VMware so am moving the whole scheme and data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It all depends on which database version , are the two database server source & destination in same network or different network . Size of the database . Generally you would be requiring expdp or rman backup to migrate to new version to maintain the consitency of the database. So in practice NFS will work much better